# PHP - trying to print a table from a reference number which has been stored in an array?

Tags: php, postgresql

Hi I'm wondering if you could help me? I'm trying to get the rows from the the database by using the reference number that I have stored in an array called items, and displaying the rows in a table, but I can only get the references number to show on the page...any help be really appreciated?

```
</head>
<h1>Shopping Cart</h1>

<body>

<?php $con = pg_connect("blah blah");
if (!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . pg_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['items'])) {
    $n = count($_POST['items']);
    for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++)
        echo $_POST['items'][$i]; 
    }

    if(!$_SESSION["selectingrows"]== 0){
        $result = pg_query ($con, "SELECT title, platform, description, price FROM CSGames     WHERE 'refnumber' = 'items[]'");

    echo "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Platform</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            </tr>";

    while($rows = pg_fetch_result($result));{
        echo"<tr>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['title'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['platform'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['description'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['price'] . "</td>";
        echo"</tr>";      
    }
    echo"</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking your while statement:

```
while($rows = pg_fetch_result($result));{
```

and should be:

```
while($rows = pg_fetch_result($result)){
```

notice the semicolon is gone.

EDIT: It appears that there are more syntax errors (this is complete):

```
$con = pg_connect("blah blah");
if (!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . pg_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['items'])) {
    $n = count($_POST['items']);
    for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++){
        echo $_POST['items'][$i]; 
    }

    if(!$_SESSION["selectingrows"]== 0){
        $result = pg_query ($con, "SELECT title, platform, description, price FROM CSGames     WHERE 'refnumber' = 'items[]'");

    echo "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Platform</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            </tr>";

    while($rows = pg_fetch_result($result));{
            echo"<tr>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['title'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['platform'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['description'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['price'] . "</td>";
            echo"</tr>";      
        }
        echo"</table>";
    }
}
```

Comment: it would appear there were more syntax errors, check that version

Comment: try to echo your query.. the reason why it display non is it checks your referral no as array(); you should use different syntax in displaying it

Comment: I echo the query and 'Resource id #4', any tips of how to show it the rows?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your problem is here:

```
$result = pg_query ($con, "SELECT title, platform, description, price FROM CSGames     WHERE 'refnumber' = 'items[]'");
```

`items[]` is not any kind of valid variable reference. You are probaly needing to do something like this:

```
$items = array();
foreach ($_POST['items'] as $item) {
    $items[] = pg_escape_string($con, $item);
}

$item_string = "'" . implode("','", $items) . "'";

$result = pg_query ($con, "SELECT title, platform, description, price FROM CSGames     WHERE 'refnumber' IN ($item_string)");
```

Note I have escaped the posted data for use in the query, I have built a string of all teh values, and then used that string in SQL `WHERE 'refnumber' IN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
</head>
<h1>Shopping Cart</h1>

<body>

<?php $con = pg_connect("blah blah");
if (!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . pg_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['items'])) {
    $n = count($_POST['items']);
    $items = array();
    for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++)
        array_push($items,$_POST['items'][$i]; // stored referrral_no in array
    }
    $items = implode("','",$items); // implode to query use
    if(!$_SESSION["selectingrows"]== 0){
        $result = pg_query ($con, "SELECT title, platform, description, price FROM CSGames     WHERE 'refnumber' IN ('$items')"); // revise query to IN

    echo "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Platform</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            </tr>";

    while($rows = pg_fetch_result($result)){
        echo"<tr>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['title'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['platform'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['description'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $rows['price'] . "</td>";
        echo"</tr>";      
    }
    echo"</table>";
}
```

try this i first stored again your items in array 
then implode it for use in query